# Discord.py modmail system

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically I want to make a modmail system which once someone dms a bot, it opens a channel where the person who DMed the bot can have a conversation through the bot. Mods would communicate through the channel.

The issue is, I know how to do most of the things, but I'm stuck at one of them. Here is my code:

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        guild = client.get_guild()
        await guild.create_text_channel(ctx.author.name)
    else:
        return
```

So that is my code which basically creates a channel named by the user's name. Now what I'm stuck in is: How do I make it send the message to that specific channel, how do I get the channel's ID or name after it got created?

Comment: How are you creating the channel? I do not see any event that triggers the bot. What is `if str(message.channel.type) == "private"` doing? How does it work?

Comment: @Dominik The event is on_message, the if section tells the bot to consider only DMs and not server messages

Comment: If you have another way to consider only DMs that you think is better than mine please tell me, even though I'm an advanced discord.py developer I still need to learn some things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few errors in your code which are blocking the event in general or do not work how you want to.

**First:** It is called `client.event`, **not** `client.event()`. You use the brackets just for the commands.

**Secondly:** You can't use `ctx.author.name` as you use a `message` event. To get the author you have to use `message.author.name`

**Thirdly:** You have to define the `await` function in order to send a message to the wanted channel.

**Have a look at the full code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        guild = client.get_guild(YourGuildID)
        modmail = await guild.create_text_channel(message.author.name)
        await modmail.send("This is a test") # Send whatever you want to
    else:
        return
```